# Want to unmute the audio while someone tries to increase the volume

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am currently trying to make a basic media player in android. See my code below that should toggle between mute and sound, but only mutes ( and never 'un-mutes' ).

```
if ( v.getId() == R.id.mute ) {
  if ( isPlaying ) {
    try {
      mPlayer.setVolume( 0, 0 );
      mute_btn.setBackgroundResource( R.drawable.img_unmute );
      isPlaying = false;

    } catch (Exception e) { }

  } else {
    if (!stopped) {
      try {
        mPlayer.setVolume(1, 1);
        mute_btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.img_mute);
        isPlaying = true;

      } catch (Exception e) { }

    } else {
      try {
        mPlayer.setVolume(0, 0);
        Log.d("song position", "=" + lastSongPos);
        playSong(lastSongPos);
        stopped = false;

      } catch (Exception e) { }
    }
  }
}
```

But I want to unmute the audio if some one tries to increase the volume in volume control seekbar. Can any body help me or give me code snippet for doing this.

Comment: Do you have a SeekBar for your volume yet?